# Is the edit count towards Copy Editor badge bugged?

Tags: bug

I was working towards the [Copy Editor badge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor) on the [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). According to the image below, today I reached 502 edits (about three hours ago), but didn't get the badge yet.

[image: Screenshot of my edit count]

**Is the edit count on that panel bugged? What's the right count?**

Then, after reading a few posts here at Meta, I ran into [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/28666/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges) that says my edit count is actually 374. So, **which count is correct?** If the correct count is 374, **what else is being counted towards the 502 count on the other panel that really doesn't count?**

#### Update

I'll be darned, but I just got the badge, 2 minutes after posting this question. Was it just a delay in the scripts that award the badge? Or is there a conspiracy going on here? Or am I just paranoid?

Comment: Cacheing can sometimes mean waiting. :)

Comment: I think in addition to caching most of the badges are awarded by scheduled jobs so a few hours is pretty normal.